# Unable to perform split in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

In splitting "201.Manjeet1" which is in column A3, desired result is "2" in one column and "Manjeet" in another column. I  need to do this in google sheets.

Comment: And how about any other values in A3?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Following Stack Overflow's guidelines on asking good questions will ensure that your questions won't get down-voted, and that you get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
=SPLIT(A3; "01.")
```

or try:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A3; "\d")&"♦"&REGEXEXTRACT(A3; "\.(.+)\d"); "♦")
```